# Adding created class to a new List and occupying object with data in one run

Tags: c#, class, arraylist, queue

My background is in javascript, but am learning C# so forgive my incorrect lingo.

I have Data.txt file and when I foreach (string line in inputFile){}, I get data like this...

Monkey 0:
Starting items: 79, 98
Operation: new = old * 19
Test: divisible by 23
If true: throw to monkey 2
If false: throw to monkey 3

Monkey 1:
Starting items: 54, 65, 75, 74
Operation: new = old + 6
Test: divisible by 19
If true: throw to monkey 2
If false: throw to monkey 0

etc...

I have a class named Monkey that looks like this...

```
public class Monkey
{
    public required int ID { get; set; }
    public Queue<int>? startingItems { get; set; }
    private void increaseWorry(int muliplier)
    {
        int item = startingItems.Dequeue();
        startingItems.Enqueue(item * muliplier / 3);
    }
    int testCheckNum { get; set; }
    int firstThrowOption { get; set; }
    int secondThrowOption { get; set; }

    public void throwToMonkey()
    {
        int worryLevel = startingItems.Dequeue();
        bool isWorryHighEnough = worryLevel % testCheckNum == 0;
        if (isWorryHighEnough)
        {
            // This Function will take each item's worry level and if isWorryHighEnough then the monkey will Enqueue to a specific Monkey, else Enqueue to a different monkey. 
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create an object using Monkey class and insert each object into a list..

```
foreach (string line in inputFile)
{
     List<Monkey> monkeys = new List<Monkey>()
     {
           if (line.Contains("Monkey"))
           {
                string[] pieces = line.Split(" ");
                Monkey.ID = Int32.Parse(pieces[1]));
           }
           if(line.Contains("Starting"))
           {
                string[] items = line.Split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
                {
                     Int32.Parse(items[i]) ? startingItems.Enqueue(items[i]) : continue;
                     // At least that is what I have in my head as I haven't gotten this far...Ill have to deal with the spaces and the commas
           }
     }
};
```

All this to say I am struggling with the steps of creating a List full of my Monkey Object defined by my class Monkey and giving each key within Monkey object data... on top of that I want to utilize the methods within the Monkey Object... but I believe that will come later after the List is created.

Comment: What you asking is not really clear, do you want to populate a list of monkey object using the file data.txt?

Comment: Are there some linebreaks in the shown data? So we can assume every line in  the file has the format `Key:Value`?

Comment: Yes i want to use the information found within the Data.txt file to fill a List of Monkey Objects... Once the txt file gets to the next monkey, it will create a new object added to the same list. Does that make sense?